# Jenkins Logged in through Admin , Not able to see Configure -Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

Few Days ago , i have installed jenkins.exe and created an Admin which has all the roles or access , and created other roles also which only have Read permission ,

Now  problem im facing is Till yesterday through Admin user i was able to see all the jekins option and now im not able to see Configure Jenkins option

kindly help me with this,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a way.

First, you navigate to `$JENKINS_HOME`. If you installed Jenkins in Windows it usually is `C:\Users\your_username\.jenkins`.

**If you are using Matrix Authorization**

Look for `<authorizationStrategy>` in `config.xml`

Now, add these lines between `<authorizationStrategy>` and `</authorizationStrategy>`:

```
    <permission>com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.Create:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.Delete:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.ManageDomains:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.Update:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.View:anonymous</permission>
    <permission>com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.View:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Build:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Configure:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Connect:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Create:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Delete:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Disconnect:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Administer:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.ConfigureUpdateCenter:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Read:anonymous</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Read:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.RunScripts:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.UploadPlugins:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Build:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Cancel:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Configure:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Create:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Delete:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Discover:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Read:anonymous</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Read:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Workspace:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Run.Delete:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Run.Update:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.View.Configure:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.View.Create:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.View.Delete:[your jenkins username]</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.View.Read:anonymous</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.View.Read:[your jenkins username]</permission>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hey  thanks it worked...i made changes in config.xml i have made   <useSecurity>no</useSecurity> and pasted abve code..it worked thanks !